# Render WordPress shortcode in post title displayed on each post in the archive page

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I was wondering if there was a way to display a shortcode that is currently working in an individual post's title on the archive page post list. Currently it is just printing the shortcode in that area. I am sure it is something I am simply overlooking (filter etc.). Below is my current code:

```
//Shortcode to add the current year into a post title
function year_shortcode () {
$year = date_i18n ('Y');
return $year;
}
add_shortcode ('year', 'year_shortcode');

add_filter( ‘the_title’, ‘do_shortcode’ );
add_filter( ‘wpseo_title’, ‘do_shortcode’ );
add_filter( ‘wpseo_metadesc’, ‘do_shortcode’ );
```

Comment: Try using the `get_the_archive_title` filter.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a shortcode?

Comment: Hi @HowardE so the reason for the shortcode was to be able to have control over where it was placed instead of appending it to the end etc.

So we wound up adding this:
`add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title' , 'do_shortcode', 25 );`

Thank you @disinfor